# ChartJS set yAxes "ticks"

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

I am trying to adjust the scales on my yAxes and cannot find any 
information that isn't outdated.

Basically, I want my yAxes to go from 0 - 100 with steps of 25.

https://codepen.io/brycesnyder/pen/wmJKyv

```
            yAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        steps: 10,
                        stepValue: 10,
                        max: 100
                    }
                }
            ]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To do this, change `stepValue: 10` to `stepSize: 25`, and remove `steps: 10,`.

[See chart.js docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size)

Comment: YOU SAVED ME!! Thank you!